# Удалить часть таблицы на PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день. 
Есть парсер который забирает таблицу с другого сервера и выводит на сайте. Но отображения всей таблицы не нужно. И сам вопрос как можно удалить ненужную часть таблицы? то есть нужно что бы отображалось только с 1 по 10 строку, а с 11 по 20 нет. На CSS делал, но таблица грузиться все ровно вся, хоть и не видно ее части. Но это мне не подходит.

Comment: Парсите результат и выводите только то, что нужно. Более конкретного ответа без приведённого вами кода, полагаю, не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Можно использовать [HTML Dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) для полученного ответа, и например, после получения таблицы работать с содержимым:

```
foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) 
   echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
```

Это простой пример, вы можете использовать, к примеру, какой-либо массив, в него собирать нужные данные, а потом генерировать таблицу вручную

Answer (score 0):

1. Спарсить всю таблицу в строку $table_string
2. Полученную строку разбить на подстроки и занести в массив с помощью `explode('<tr>',$table_string)`, нулевой элемент полученного массива будет содержать часть таблицы до первого `tr`, а все остальные строки.
3. Удалить элементы массива от 11 и далее, через `array_splice`
4. Вывести массив на экран c недостающими `<tr>`, в конце дописать `</table>`